# change tweet content

Tags: button, twitter

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="ivo_sanz">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

I got this on twitter.com and I wanted to change what is going to be twitted.

for example I want to tweet

```
"tweet me please"
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
 <a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Tweet%20me%20please" class="twitter-hashtag-button" data-size="large" data-via="ivo_sanz">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```